# PayPal "Subscription" add to cart, with tax and shipping

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart, subscription

Is there any way to create a shopping cart through PayPal that allows shoppers to add subscriptions for multiple items into a shopping cart then check out all at once?

This is easily done with regularly priced items, but does not work with recurring subscription items. Tax and shipping also need to be added to the subscription (based on geographic location) because it is a physical product.

PayPal customer support and technical forums have been no help in solving this.

Subsequently if this is not possible with PayPal, does anyone have suggestions for another payment processor that could handle this task eg authorize.net?

Comment: Hey I'm looking to do the same thing, did you ever find out how to do this or any other service that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscription buttons won't handle this.  They can only handle a single subscription, for a single item, in each session.

I would suggest using Express Checkout.  Using Express Checkout, you can charge the buyer for multiple items upfront, and set up a recurring payments profile at the same time.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/